# Add Html.BeginForm with jQuery in MVC view

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have some info boxes that all are loaded in with Ajax calling a function in my controller and then building the HTML.

I need some edit functionality for these info boxes which will simply replace the static text with a form. I know how I would go about doing this in regular HTML but I would like to use Html.BeginForm so that I may handle it in the controller.

This is how I wanted to load in my form (it's almost the same code as the one for loading the static info boxes)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomerInfoById/")' + id,
    type: 'post',
    traditional: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        $.each(result.CustomerInfo, function (index, customerInfo) {
            $('#infoBox' + customerInfo.ID).html(/* html form goes here */);
        });
    }
})
```

This is how I want to build my form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @model CustomerInfo

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.InfoText, new { @class = "form-control col-12-md", @style = "max-width: none", @rows = "5" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InfoTypeId, new SelectList(InfoTypeList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", @style = "max-width: none" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Gem" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

Comment: What is the question? SO exists to help all programmers, not just you. Please rephrase the subject of your post into a clear question that makes it easy for people with a similar problem, to find your post.

Comment: The mvc helper classes are literally just shorthand server side html that is compiled at run time. Just write the html markup in jquery, it evaluates as the same thing.

Comment: @Jacob OP has defined their question. They want to add mvc helper classes to their form using jQuery, which is pointless.

Comment: He needs to do some googling on how to create a view with a Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do it by making a new Controller ActionMethod using the `customerInfo.ID` as a parameter, which renders your Form as a Partial View.

The Form will need to be given a a hidden field for the ID, so the Forms Posts can be distinguished from one another if they happen.

Call the new ActionMethod using additional `$.ajax()` calls inside your loop, each with a success function that passes the result into the `.html()` statement.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll first be able to try it out on Monday as I suddenly had to leave the office right after I asked my question.